# Railway Simulation Graphics Engine

Tags: .net, user-interface, graphics, 2d

I'm currently looking for a suitable graphics engine and suggestions on how to implement a **railway simulation GUI**. This is for a central railway network control system.

I intend to generate a display similar to the following:

[A railway section network diagram commonly found at signal boxes](http://www.trainweb.org/districtdave/assets/images/Slide_1_small.jpg)

My problem comes with showing the real time position of trains using the network:

What would be the best way of representing trains on a diagram similar to the one above? I'm currently thinking of having numbered and color coded rectangles overlayed on the track.

Have you any suggestions or recommendations for a suitable 2D graphics engine for the .net framework?

Ross

Comment: Using graphics for .NET, you could try XNA [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA).

Comment: Even if this is not gaming related, you could find useful stuff also on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fancy rolling your own rather than using a 3rd party graphics engine, you could easily use the WPF Canvas, and some other controls like Rectangle and TextBlock.

It should be relatively simple to build something like the image you linked to in WPF.